# R Markdown: Is there a way to print out the code of a sourced file in the console (and not the Rmd file itself) while it's running?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am new to using R markdown and am attempting to source a regular R script inside an Rmd file. This R script is fairly lengthy and I'd like to be able to see the output of each line (only in the console and not printed in the r markdown file) as it's being ran just in case an error or something unexpected pops up. Is this possible?

Here's my Render file:

```
main_dir<-"filepath"
sub_dir<-paste0(format(Sys.time(),'%Y%m%d.'), 0)

if (!dir.exists(file.path(main_dir, sub_dir))) {
  dir.create(file.path(main_dir, sub_dir))
  path<-paste0(main_dir, sub_dir)
} else {
  folders<-dir("filepath", full.names = FALSE)
  folders<-as.data.table(folders)
  date<-paste0(format(Sys.time(),'%Y%m%d.'))
  folders<-folders[folders %like% date]
  versions<-sub('.*\\.', '', folders$folders)
  version<-as.integer(max(versions))+1
  
  sub_dir<-paste0(format(Sys.time(),'%Y%m%d.'), version)
  dir.create(file.path(main_dir, sub_dir))
  path<-paste0(main_dir, sub_dir)
}

dir.create(file.path(main_dir, sub_dir, "response_data"))
dir.create(file.path(main_dir, sub_dir, "external_model_data"))
dir.create(file.path(main_dir, sub_dir, "supplementary_data"))
dir.create(file.path(main_dir, sub_dir, "variables"))

code_directory <- paste0("source_file_path")

rmarkdown::render(input = paste0(code_directory, "data_stats.Rmd"),
                  output_format = c("pdf_document"),
                  output_file = c(paste0("stats", sub_dir, ".pdf")),
                  clean=FALSE,
                  output_dir = paste0("output_file_path", sub_dir)
)
```

data_stats file

````
---
title: "Symptom Survey"
author: "B"
date: "2021-08-25"
output: pdf_document
geometry: margin=2cm
---

```{r beginning, include=FALSE}
source("source_file_path.R", local = knitr::knit_global())
```

```{r zip_table, echo=FALSE, results ='asis', fig.height=7, out.width="100%",warning=F, message = F, fig.align="center"}
kable(zcta_missingness_month, caption = "ZCTA % Missingness By Month")
```

```{r age_table, echo=FALSE, results ='asis', fig.height=7, out.width="100%",warning=F, message = F, fig.align="center"}
kable(age_response, caption = "Age Response % By Month")
```

```{r educ_table, echo=FALSE, results ='asis', fig.height=7, out.width="100%",warning=F, message = F, fig.align="center"}
kable(educ_response, caption = "Education Response % By Month")
```

```{r ss, echo=FALSE, results ='asis', fig.height=4, out.width="100%",warning=F, message = F, fig.align="center"}
ggplot(sample_size_week, aes(week, N)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + ylab("count") + ggtitle("Respondent Count By #Week") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))

```

```{r age_plot, echo=FALSE, results ='asis', fig.height=7, out.width="100%",warning=F, message = F, fig.align="center"}
age_dist

```

```{r age_weight_plot, eval=FALSE, echo=FALSE, results ='asis', fig.height=7, out.width="100%",warning=F, message = F, fig.align="center"}
age_dist_weight

```
````

Comment: I think it's hard to get the code to display in the console, but you can show progress messages by using `message("Some text")` in your code, with chunk option `message=FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `echo` argument to `TRUE` as in:

`source("source_file_path.R", echo = TRUE, local = knitr::knit_global())`